# laravel-excel: how to start writing rows from row 3?

Tags: laravel-excel

I have a full working export using latest laravel-excel (3.1.34).

I need to add some text before first data rowm, so I want to write header row starting from row 3

How can I do this?

The `headingRows` method is used internally only when *importing* and ignored while exporting.

As workaround, can I 'add rows manually' in the 'after sheet' event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented `WithEvents`

I did this and it worked

```
public function registerEvents(): array
    {
       return [
            AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) {

                $sheet = $event->sheet->getDelegate();

                $sheet->insertNewRowBefore(1,3);
            },
        ];

}
```